# How to modify trac to create own custom Link format (TracLinks)

Tags: python, customization, trac, issue-tracking

In the open-source [trac issue tracking software](http://trac.edgewall.org), when you write text in the wiki or ticket comments, you can link to a ticket using `#1234` or you can link to a code changeset using `r1234`. This is the documentation: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracLinks

I would like to define my own link format. 3 examples of what I'd like to do:

1. I'd like `a1234` to link to a [acunote](http://www.acunote.com/promo) ticket (which complements trac but is external to our trac installation).
2. I'd like `ge2a1b3caadd0986e3e3d316c01965a2495329b87` to link to a [github](https://github.com/) commit (i.e. https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/commit/e2a1b3caadd0986e3e3d316c01965a2495329b87).
3. I'd like `CComponent` to link to the [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com) documentation (i.e. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent)

Does anyone know how I can do this using trac v0.12. Should I use a Macro? a plugin? a [Genshi template](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#SiteAppearance)? It strikes me as something that could be quite simple if you have the know how?

---

Comment: i had similar requirements and trac was really not suited. imo it is over complciated has a lot of components and it could be a lot easier. we now use mantis. its just a webpage and a database and runs like a charm and features everything you could ever wish for. i heard that redmine was good too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want this exact syntax, you have no other choice than to create a plugin and have a `Component` that implements the `IWikiSyntaxProvider` [interface](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser//trunk/trac/wiki/api.py?rev=10617&marks=172-196#L170).

If you can live with a slightly different syntax, for example `[a:1234]` for the acunote ticket, `[g:e2a1b3caadd0986e3e3d316c01965a2495329b87]` for the github changeset, and `[y:CComponent]` for the Yii documentation, then you could add the following entries to the [InterMapTxt](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/InterMapTxt) page of your Trac installation:

```
a    http://my.acunote.site/ticket/$1                  # Acunote ticket $1
g    https://github.com/peritor/webistrano/commit/$1   # Changeset $1 on Github
y    http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/$1        # Yii documentation for $1
```

Comment: The brackets are even optional, you can also write `a:1234`, `g:e2a1b3caadd0986e3e3d316c01965a2495329b87` and `y:CComponent`.

Comment: This Syntax is fine for me. Wow - can't believe how easy it was to accomplish. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Remy is correct in that your syntax is potentially making this more difficult.  The standard Trac syntax for links is `resource_type:link_specifier`.  If you are able to use that syntax instead, then it's fairly straightforward to use Inter-Wiki links to accomplish what you want.

If that's not an option, you can do what you describe with a custom-built plugin.  It's not as difficult as it might sound, you can use the source from an existing plugin as an example.  I have done this several times before, all you really need is a regular expression that represents the syntax you wish to use and one that represents the format of the resulting link, as well as about one page of Python code.

**Update:**  For an example of how to do this via a Trac plugin, there is sample code and a description in the [official Trac documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/IWikiSyntaxProviderExample).